# Readstatechange Fires prematurely in jQuery XMLHttpRequest to MVC5 Action

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a jQuery function to upload an image:

```
        $("#addPictureForm").submit(function() {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var fd = new FormData();
            fd.append("file", $('#fileSelect')[0].files[0]);
            var id = @Model.myId;
            fd.append("id", id);
            var token = $('#__AjaxAntiForgeryForm input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();
            fd.append("__RequestVerificationToken", token);

            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
                    alert(xhr.responseText); // this never fires...
                }
            }
            xhr.open("POST", "/Images/AddPicture/", true);
            xhr.send(fd);
        });
```

It is handled by this Controller Action:

```
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public string AddPicture(HttpPostedFileBase file, int id)
    {
        if (file == null)
            throw new Exception("File name must be selected.");

        var buffer = new byte[file.ContentLength];

        ... store image, get guid for it ...

        // return a uri that can be plugged into the img tag
        return Url.HttpRouteUrl("Default", new {controller = "Images", action = "GetImage", id = Id, picGuid = pictureGuid});
    }
```

The onreadystatechange event fires right after this function is called if you check only for readystate ==4, instead of waiting for a response. If I add the status of 200, then it never fires. The function works to store the image and if I refresh the page, I will see it show up. How can I catch the response from this action?

Comment: you mean get xhr.responseText when xhr.status == 200?

Comment: I had tried that - I have updated the code to include this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the action is a submit, it is posting the call and the page gets reloaded. I didn't catch that even looking in the developer window.

There was also a problem with the Controller returning a string. I was not successful in getting the uri to the picture I needed back until I used a return Json(...) approach.

Once I removed the form element surrounding the add picture button and made it purely a button click handler instead of a submit event, it was finishing up on the same page and calling the success event.

I didn't like forcing the user to click an additional time to perform the upload, so I also put the upload in the change event of the file input element.

Here is what I ended up with:

HTML:

```
    <div class="col-md-10"> 
        <fieldset>
            Add Picture: <input type="file" id="fileSelect" />
        </fieldset>
    </div>
```

jQuery:

```
// AddPicture - Trigger when file selected
$("#fileSelect").change(function(e) {
    // Create FormData object
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("file", $('#fileSelect')[0].files[0]);
    var id = @Model.Id;
    fd.append("id", id);
    var token = $('#__AjaxAntiForgeryForm input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();
    fd.append("__RequestVerificationToken", token);

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Images/AddPicture/',
        type: "POST",
        contentType: false, // Not to set any content header
        processData: false, // Not to process data
        data: fd,
        success: function(result) {
            alert("picture loaded successfully - do something here");
        },
        error: function(err) {
            alert(err.statusText);
        }
    });
});
```

Controller:

```
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddPicture(HttpPostedFileBase file, int id)
    {
        if (file == null)
            throw new Exception("File name must be selected.");

        var buffer = new byte[file.ContentLength];

        file.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, file.ContentLength);

        var returnString = StorePicAndCreateReferenceGuid(buffer);

        return Json(Url.HttpRouteUrl("Default", 
            new {controller = "Images", action = "GetImage", 
            id = Id, picGuid = pictureGuid}));
    }
```

In my code, I am able to then use the reference I returned to load the uploaded picture in-place on the page.

I probably would have been fine sticking with XMLHttpRequest, but had switched to the ajax call, so I stuck with it.